# new ArrayCollection() in __construct does not work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Although an ArrayCollection is properly initialized in __construct, trying any of the methods (contains(), add()) does not work and throws an exception (Call to a member function contains() on null, Call to a member function add() on null).

Property:

```
/**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Trade", inversedBy="businesses")
     */
    private $trades;
```

Construct:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->trades = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Method:

```
public function addTrade($trade)
    {
        if (!$this->trades->contains($trade)) {
            $this->trades->add($trade);
        }
    }
```

Command:

```
$pro = new Business();
...
...
...
$pro->addtrade($proTrade);
```

And then in throws the exception. Other ArrayCollections for the entity work fine (declared the same way in construct).

Cache is cleared, of course.

Comment: Do you use use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection; ?

Comment: Could you reduce this to a minimum reproducible example and post the full code along with the exception?

Comment: Yes, Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection is imported. Regarding minimum reproducible example, I will try to do it, but it will take time, as the Class is quite complicated and there are many relations. While testing, it appears that NONE of the adders work.

Comment: I think I found the culprit. VSCode decided to autoimport the entity in a way I don't understand (Proxy?). So, instead of 'use App\Entity\Business;', I had 'use Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Business;'.

Comment: Can you do inside of the function add, `$trade->setBusiness($this)`.

Check this example https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#association-management-methods

Comment: Don't use the proxy.  That can cause all kinds of problems..  Are you testing with an entity loaded from a database?  If so the constructor is never called.  Doctrine takes care of initializing the collections.  So it could be a mapping error of some kind.  If it is happening with new Entity then I don't know what the problem is.